# assignment sql for finding branches with atleast 2 copies of every boook

Tags: mysql

```
   Q. List the branch id and name of all branches that have atleast 2 copies of every  
       book.
```

Tables:

```
    BOOK (Book_ISBN [pk], Title, Publisher_Name [fk])
    BOOK_COPIES (Book_ISBN [pk,fk], Branch_ID [pk,fk], Num_Copies)
    LIBRARY_BANCH (Branch_ID [pk], Branch_Name, Address)
```

However, I tried doing this question but problem has been that  checking for 2 copies.

Comment: Presumably there is also a table called `BOOKS`?

Answer (score 1):

You might find this article on [relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) useful.

```
SELECT L.Branch_ID,
       L.Branch_Name
FROM   LIBRARY_BRANCH L
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   BOOK B
                   WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                                     FROM   BOOK_COPIES BC
                                     WHERE  BC.Book_ISBN = B.Book_ISBN
                                            AND Num_Copies >= 2
                                            AND L.Branch_ID = BC.Branch_ID))
```